# How to use dynamic rule validation in jquery

Tags: jquery, validation, rule

### im try to do this, it's error

---

> $.each(data, function(i, item) {
>       $('#'+item.field_id).rules('add', checkSeqNoFormat());
>   }

---

```
$.validator.addMethod(
        "checkSeqNoFormat",
        function (value, element, requiredValue) {
            if(value=="123456789"){
                return true;
            }else{
                setMsgError(element);
                return false;
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: paste your full code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('#'+item.field_id).rules('add', {
        checkSeqNoFormat: true
  });
```